# Why are ions much more efficient than electrons at beam-induced deposition?

Tags: decomposition, gas-phase-chemistry

I have recently been reading about electron beam induced deposition and ion beam deposition. The idea is to send a high energy (5-30 kV) beam of electrons/ions focused down to a spot on a material and open a gas precursor source. The beam somehow breaks down the bonds of the precursor gas, and some of the components of the gas get deposited on the sample. (e.g. carbon, silver,  platinum,...)

My question is, **why does this deposition process work more quickly with ions than electrons with the same kinetic energy?** From what I've seen in the literature, ions like Gallium can be 10-1000 tines faster at deposition than electrons at the same energy.

Comment: The stopping power (energy loss) is much higher for ions. See, for example, https://www.nist.gov/pml/stopping-power-range-tables-electrons-protons-and-helium-ions - a 10keV electron in silicon has a stopping power of about 17 MeV cm$^{2}$/g while a 10keV alpha has an electronic stopping of about 212 and a nuclear stopping of over a 1000 MeV cm$^{2}$/g. So, the ion is much more likely to deposit energy at or near the surface where it counts for deposition.

Comment: @Jon Custer, is there some intuition for the difference in stopping power?